# How to resolve the 'CKEditor Error: "can't convert null to object"' error

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have installed the ckeditor5 via npm;

`npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`

After that I have included the editor as [described in the manual](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html). Via the following command:

`import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

But when I try to execute the sample code they provide in this manual:

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

I get the error *CKEditorError: "can't convert null to object"*. When inspecting the **ClassicEditor** object, I notice it is a function which needs to be initialised via `new ClassicEditor()` with the properties *name*, *builtinPlugins* & *defaultConfig*.

When creating an object via this method. A new object with a whole array of properties like *_events*, *keystrokes* & *ui* is being created.

So there goes something wrong, initializing the ckeditor. Where should I look to resolve this issue? Since I followed all the steps as described in the manual, I suppose I need to look at my Angularjs / WebPack configuration. But wouldn't know where to look for, since I had no issues with all my other 32 packages.

Answer (score 4):

That probably means the element you are passing doesn't exists.
A common mistake would be trying to instantiate the editor before the element.
Make sure you add `<div id="editor"></div>` before calling `ClassicEditor.create()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, this error generally occurs when you are calling the create() method before the dom initializes.

Comment: In my case selector issue .editor Thanks for ur Info

Answer (score 1):

may be you init in created() instead of mounted

for example

```js
export default {
  name: 'ClassicEditor',

  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.initEditor()
  },

  methods: {

    initEditor() {
    
      ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#ykEditor'), {
        language: 'zh-cn',
      }).then(editor => {
        const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('#toolbar-container');
        toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
        this.editor = editor
      }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
      });
    },

  }

}
```

init method should be in mounted()

Answer (score 0):

You will save your nerves by implementing `queue` pattern.
Somewhere in `common.js`

```
if (!window.queue) window.queue = {};

function addQueue(check, fnc, arg = null) {
  let key = Date.now();
  while (window.queue[key]) key++;
  window.queue[key] = { check: check, fnc: fnc, arg: arg }
}

function runQueue() {
  Object.entries(window.queue).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    if (item && item.check()) {
      item.fnc(item.arg);
      delete window.queue[key];
    }
  });
  setTimeout(runQueue, 100);
}
runQueue();
```

Somewhere on `ckeditor` page

```
function ckeInit(selector = false, readonly = false) {
  addQueue(
    function () { 
      return !!ClassicEditor && !!document.querySelector(selector || '.ckeditor');
    },
    function () {
      ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector(selector || '.ckeditor'), {})
       .when.then...so-on.readonlySettings
    }, null
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a `div` instead of an input/textarea, and err caused of `sourceElement` manual data set/get

```
    .then(editor => {
      window.editor = editor;
      editor.setData(editor.sourceElement.value);
      !readonly && editor.model.document.on('change:data', (evt, data) => {
        editor.sourceElement.value = editor.getData();
      });
    })
```

solved by adding a row

```
    if (editor.sourceElement && editor.sourceElement.value)
```